# Yaml script for adding timeoutinminutes in Build Pipeline VSTS

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, build-pipeline

When I'm building my Test solution(set of unit test cases), I'm getting the following error, need to add timeoutinminutes in the below yaml script.

> [Error 1]
>   The job running on agent Hosted Agent ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134

Find yaml script below:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/**.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: VSTest@2
  timeoutInMinutes: 1200
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    runInParallel: true
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Comment: If you use a private project with Microsoft hosted agent you can't put timeout more than 60 minuets.

Comment: you posted the link that answers your question along with your error-message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you confused should be why you have specify `timeoutInMinutes` as `1200`, and why still facing the error:

> "The job running on agent Hosted Agent ran longer than the maximum
> time of 60 minutes."

As D.J said, the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts) in the error message has been give you the explanation.

Your project should be private, right? If this, then you could not avoid the limitation of hosted agent for private project.

[Capabilities and limitations of Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#capabilities-and-limitations):

> **Public project:** 10 free Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs that can run for up to **360** minutes (6 hours) each time
>
> **Private project:** One free parallel job that can run for up to **60** minutes each time

Though you specified the timeout as 1200 minutes, but, unfortunately, it can not override the limitations of the server.

---

The best solution for you to make your tests could not be limited by Timeout is [install and use private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

Or you think **360** minutes could be enough for you, then you can try with change project as **public**. But I do not recommend this way if you think the scripts and repos is very private for you.